# Stopping ZSH from correcting a single command

Tags: zsh

*Every single time* I try to use `npm` in `zsh` it asks me if I meant `nm`. It's gotten very annoying now. I like the auto correct feature, though. How can I turn it off for the `npm` command?

Comment: Zsh wouldn't autocorrect if it noticed that `npm` was a valid command. Why doesn't it think that it's a valid command? Is this an installed executable in your `$PATH`? Do you have execution permissions on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've just installed `npm` and you're still running a zsh instance from before the installation, run `hash -rf` to rebuild the command cache (or more precisely `hash npm`). Instances of zsh started after the installation will pick up this command when they build their cache.

Answer (score 0):

You could put:

```
alias npm='nocorrect npm'
```

in your profile script. Not very pretty but effective.